# How can I connect Arduino nano 33 IOT and PN532 module?

Tags: arduino

I am using the example code of readMifare

This is my code

```
`
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>
 
// If using the breakout with SPI, define the pins for SPI communication.
#define PN532_SCK  (13)
#define PN532_MOSI (11)
#define PN532_SS   (10) // (4) <- changed to D9 for IRQ pin, refer to schematic
#define PN532_MISO (12)
 
// If using the breakout or shield with I2C, define just the pins connected
// to the IRQ and reset lines.  Use the values below (2, 3) for the shield!
#define PN532_IRQ   (2)
#define PN532_RESET (3) // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield
 
// Uncomment just _one_ line below depending on how your breakout or shield
// is connected to the Arduino:
 
// Use this line for a breakout with a SPI connection:
 Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SCK,PN532_MOSI,PN532_MISO,PN532_SS);
 
// Use this line for a breakout with a hardware SPI connection.  Note that
// the PN532 SCK, MOSI, and MISO pins need to be connected to the Arduino's
// hardware SPI SCK, MOSI, and MISO pins.  On an Arduino Uno these are
// SCK = 13, MOSI = 11, MISO = 12.  The SS line can be any digital IO pin.
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SS);
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SCK);
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_MOSI);
//Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_MISO);
// Or use this line for a breakout or shield with an I2C connection:
// Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_IRQ, PN532_RESET);
 
#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
// for Zero, output on USB Serial console, remove line below if using
// also change #define in Adafruit_PN532.cpp library file
   #define Serial SerialUSB
#endif
 
void setup(void) {
    #ifndef ESP8266
    while (!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero
    #endif
 
    /* This PN532 I2C example is modified by DotoriKing from original Adafruit PN532 example */
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.print("\r\n\r\nPN532 NFC Start by DotoriKing");
 
    nfc.begin();
 
    uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
    if (! versiondata)
    {
        Serial.print("\r\nDidn't find PN53x board");
        while (1); // halt
    }
 
    // Got ok data, print it out!
    Serial.print("\r\nFound chip PN5");
    Serial.print((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX);
    Serial.print("\r\nFirmware ver. ");
    Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC);
    Serial.print('.');
    Serial.print((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);
 
    // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
    // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
    // the default behaviour of the PN532.
    nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);
 
    // configure board to read RFID tags
    nfc.SAMConfig();
 
    Serial.print("\r\nWaiting for an ISO14443A card");
}
 
void loop(void)
{
    boolean success;
    uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };    // Buffer to store the returned UID
    uint8_t uidLength;              // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)
 
    // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
    // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
    // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
    success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength);
 
    if (success)
    {
        Serial.print("\r\nFound a card!");
        Serial.print("\r\nUID Length: ");
        Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);
        Serial.print(" bytes");
        Serial.print("\r\nUID Value: ");
 
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < uidLength; i++)
        {
            Serial.print(" 0x");
            Serial.print(uid[i], HEX);
        }
 
        // Wait 1 second before continuing
        delay(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        // PN532 probably timed out waiting for a card
        Serial.print("\r\nTimed out waiting for a card");
    }
}
`
```

I want to connect the device at SPI setting.

I have PN532 and BUSIO library. also I connected 3.3V and ground normally and set the PN532 board according to the SPI button.

but I can only see didn't find PN53x an error message.
How can I fix the situation?

Comment: What is your board's jumper settings for select the protocol to be used? What library you are using. Please also provide your minimum code or else we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Found a solution here:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/library-pn532-for-nano-33-ble/894185

managed to get this code to work on arduino nano 33 iot by modifying the library Adafruit_PN532.cpp

old code
new Adafruit_SPIDevice(ss, clk, miso, mosi, 1000000, SPI_BITORDER_LSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);}

new code
new Adafruit_SPIDevice(ss, clk, miso, mosi, 100000, SPI_BITORDER_LSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);}

Answer (score 0):

For my fellow breatherins on a quest to connect the PN532 and Nano 33 IoT by I2C protocol, use the DFRobot_PN532 library. It's the only way I got my project working.

https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_PN532